# Is it possible to access a UITableView's ScrollView In Code From A Nib?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Right now I am creating a UITableView in a FlipsideView nib.  I don't seem to be able to change the background of the table view from within interface builder.  I can fix this by creating an outlet and then setting the background.  However, I want to give the scroll view rounded corners in order to create a look similar to the iPhone weather/stock app table views.  Is there a way to access the scroll view's property in code so that I can set the rounded corners?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

A `UITableView` doesn't have a `UIScrollView`, it **is** a `UIScrollView`. UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView as can be seen it the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview). Any properties of functionality of `UIScrollView` you want to access can be directly accessed via the table view.

Similarly, `UITableViewDelegate`s are all `UIScrollViewDelegate`s.

Comment: The bold "is" was as far as I needed to read to fix my issue!

Answer (score 4):

You can add a corner radius to any view's layer. It would look something like this:

```
theTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f; // Or whatever radius you wanted to set
```

I believe you'll need to link to the `QuartzCore` framework and import the `QuartzCore.h` header, too.

This will round the corners of the table similar to how they appear in the flipside of Weather.app.

Comment: You also need to set the layer's masksToBounds property with [[theTableView layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];

Comment: I can do that, but it also makes it very slow.  It is not nearly as ni ce as the table views in apple's application

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the table views for the Stocks and Weather applications are simply single-section grouped table views (`UITableViews` initialized with the `UITableViewStyleGrouped` style).  You shouldn't need to customize anything about the table view's `UIScrollView` properties to generate this same rounded-corner effect.

Comment: Its not quite the same.  On Apple's application, the rounded corners always stay in the same spot.  If you just stick a Grouped section there.  The rounded corners will scroll up and down with the tableview itself.