# How to detect which UITableView is scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

Im detecting `UITableView` scrolling in this way

`

```
  - (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate: (BOOL)decelerate{
isDragging_msg = FALSE;
[tblSongs reloadData];
```

}

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
isDecliring_msg = FALSE;
[tblSongs reloadData]; }


- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
isDragging_msg = TRUE;
```

}

```
 - (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
isDecliring_msg = TRUE; }
```

`

but I have to load sevaral `UITableViews` Under this detection I have to reload each tables seperately. So how I can detect which table is currently scrolling.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Table view is a scroll view as mentioned here: [Is it possible to access a UITableView's ScrollView In Code From A Nib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703023/is-it-possible-to-access-a-uitableviews-scrollview-in-code-from-a-nib)

So you can just check the scroll view passed in each delegate method whether the scroll view is the table view you want, for example:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    if (scrollView == tblSongs) {
        isDragging_msg = FALSE;
        [tblSongs reloadData];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think `scrollView` parameter in all these methods is for?

Comment: can I add some tag only for the scrollview of the table?

Comment: or scroll view get the same tag number of the UITableView

Answer (score 0):

You can detect event on each table. [UITableView event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642699/uitableview-scroll-event)

To receive touch events on the UITableView use:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  //<your stuff>

  [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   //<your stuff>

   [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
  //<your stuff>

  [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
   //<your stuff>
   [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

and can reload any particular tableview. Thanks