# UITableView get UIScrollView for customization

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have category for `UIScrollView` for customization

I need get `UIScrollView`.

I try

```
UIScrollView *scroll = nil;
for (UIView* subview in self.tableView.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"%i", self.tableView.subviews.count);

    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        scroll = (UIScrollView *)subview;
        //some code
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. How I can get `ScrollView`? Thanks

Comment: this is very nice explanation take a look:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703023/is-it-possible-to-access-a-uitableviews-scrollview-in-code-from-a-nib

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, not a subview (or vice-versa as your code tries), so you should just use the table view directly.

Answer (score 1):

UIScrollView is not subview but UIScrollView is superclass of UITableView you can call method or get variable of UIScrollView by through UIScrollView, If you want to get UIScrollView you can use by this

```
var scroll = self.tableView as UIScrollView
//some code
```

Or you want to compare you can use

```
if scrollView == self.tableView {
    //some code 
}
```

Comment: thanks it works , I required it to pass UIScrollView as a variable in a method to check scrollview content offset position.